# can I send my gmail using mailutils from my terminal

Tags: gmail, mailutils

I want to set up mailutils on my terminal problem is that I don't want to create another email account. My question is, is it possible to use my gmail from my terminal ?

Comment: What is the problem? You can setup mailutils or whatever mail program to use gmail server.

Comment: You need to setup postfix first. Is that the question?

Comment: For sending email, [this](http://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay) (or [this](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/)) may help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to send mail from terminal is to use `sendemail` program. Install it

```
sudo apt-get install sendemail
```

Bow you can send it by this command

```
sendemail -f <from_address> -t <to_address> -u "<subject>" -m "<message>" -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -o tls=yes -xu <your_gmail_address>
```

It will ask for password, which unfortunately will be displayed on screen.

To make it shorter to enter, you can make an alias in `bashrc`.

There are also very many ways to do it. I use `git send-email`.

You can setup mailutils to the same server.

Comment: I missed your message (only partly rendered when I looked earlier).  My bad.